# Storing dry yeast in freezer?

Tags: baking, yeast

Is it true that storing dry active yeast in the freezer helps to retain its lifting power? How long can it be stored this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forever?

Years, anyway.

I bought 2 pounds of yeast at Sam's Club about 3 years ago and it still works great.

Just make sure you keep it very dry and very cold.